# Default statement position in switch

Tags: switch-statement

```
switch(2){
    default : System.out.println("I am Default block");
    case 1 : System.out.println("in 1");
    case 2 : System.out.println("in 2");
}
```

The output : in 2
and if

```
switch(2){

case 1 : System.out.println("in 1");
case 2 : System.out.println("in 2");

default : System.out.println("I am Default block");
```

}

And the output is: in 2
I am Default block.

Does the positioning of the default statement behaves differently?

Comment: Which language are you programming in?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the position of the default block, it's the use (or non-use in your case) of the `break` statement.

Once a case has been matched, the default behaviour is for the code to cascade through the rest of the cases.

To achieve the behaviour you desire, try

```
switch (2)
{
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("in 1"); 
        break;
    case 2: 
        System.out.println("in 2"); 
        break;
    default: 
        System.out.println("I am Default block"); 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kathy Siera SCJP book do say that position of default: matters and if present in between the case statements, it follows the fall-through. 
But practically it does not follow.

```
    int a = 10;

    switch (a) 
    {
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Its 5");
    default:
        System.out.println("Its default");
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Its 10");
    case 20:
        System.out.println("Its 20");
    }
```

Output:

Its 10

Its 20

Comment: It does follow, when you use a value which is only matching default, like "30" you will see "its default, its 10 its 20".